# sqlite3_prepare_v2 throws SQLITE_ERROR in iPhone code

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I have a piece of code that used to work, and other iterations of it that DO work within the same app, and have compared code, and they are identical in structure.  This is driving me INSANE!!!!!!

In this instance, sqlite3_prepare_v2 is throwing one of those useless SQLITE_ERROR exceptions.  Apparently, it can FIND the database, and OPEN the database, but it can't prepare a statement for it.

Does ANYONE have any ideas?  I'm desperate here.

```
 second_maindatabaseName = @"database.db";
NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
second_maindatabasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:second_maindatabaseName];

// Setup the database object
sqlite3 *database;
// Init the entry requirements Array
BOOL success;
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:second_maindatabasePath];
if(!success) {
NSString *databasePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:second_maindatabaseName];
[fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:second_maindatabasePath error:nil];
[fileManager release];
}
if(sqlite3_open([second_maindatabasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

value1 = [defaults stringForKey:kConst1];   
value2 = [defaults stringForKey:kConst2];   
value3 = [defaults stringForKey:kConst3];   
value4 = [defaults stringForKey:kConst4];   
const char *sqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE Field1 = ? AND Field2 = ? AND Field3 = ? AND Field4 = ?";
sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
int error_code = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL);
if(error_code == SQLITE_OK) {
// Loop through the results and add them to the feeds array
sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement,1,[value1 UTF8String],-1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement,2,[value2 UTF8String],-1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement,3,[value3 UTF8String],-1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement,4,[value4 UTF8String],-1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
// Read the data from the result row
NSString *aNewValue = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];
                        }
} 
sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
}
sqlite3_close(database);
```

Comment: what is the value of error_code after the call?

Comment: Just trying to figure out what error it's throwing... it's catching the error code being returned by sqlite3_prepare_v2, so I can evaluate that in the debugger as I step through it.

Comment: @DonDickinson, In my case its returning value 1. i.e.
`#define SQLITE_ERROR        1   /* SQL error or missing database */` 
Database is present as it in bundle and `sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK` and also statement 'const char *sql = "SELECT * FROM Images";' was working. But this "const char *sql = "SELECT Image FROM Images WHERE CatagoryId=2";' is not working its getting execute in sqlManager but not in ios.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *aNewValue = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];
```

Try the following format:

```
char *rowData_ptr = (char *) sqlite3_column_text (statement_ptr, 1)
fieldValue_ptr    = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:rowData_ptr];
```

You do not allocate "aNewValue"

Answer (score 0):

In my case its returning value 1. i.e.

```
 #define SQLITE_ERROR 1 /* SQL error or missing database */
```

Database is present as it in bundle and
`sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK` and also statement `'const char *sql = "SELECT * FROM Images";'` was working.
But this `"const char *sql = "SELECT Image FROM Images WHERE CatagoryId=2";'` is not working its getting execute in sqlManager but not in ios.

It was not working as i changed the column in the database.
I corrected it by updating database

- reset the simulator.
- delete and add the database in bundle.
- clean and build.

  It was reading the old database in simulator.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same error because I was trying to perform an insertion into a table which didn't have a column I specified:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO table_name (record_id,record_from_date,record_to_date,blister_status,blister_size) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?);
```

while the table didn't have the column `blister_size`.